# SQLite Case Statement

Tags: sql, sqlite, case

All the values in the orders table are there and are integers. I am not sure what I am doing wrong syntax wise. it keeps giving me this error

near "range": syntax error:

```
select 
    case
        when AMOUNT < 2000 then "low price"
        when amount between 3000 and 2000 then "medium price"
        else "high price"
    end as price range, 
    count(*)
    from orders
    group by 1;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want spaces in names then use backticks

```
as `price range`
```